# Cannot parse resolution '15 error in PineScript

Tags: pine-script

I have written a strategy based on the SuperTrend indicator that buys when the SuperTrend gives a buy signal with a 5% stop loss and 10% take profit, and squares off at 3 pm. It gets compiled but throws this error: "Cannot parse resolution '15"

//@version=4

`strategy("Supertrend Strategy", overlay=true)`

// input variables

`stopLossPct = input(5, title="Stop Loss Percentage") takeProfitPct = input(10, title="Take Profit Percentage") squareOffTime = input("15:00:00", title="Square Off Time")`

// SuperTrend indicator

`Periods = input(title="ATR Period", type=input.integer, defval=10) src = input(hl2, title="Source") Multiplier = input(title="ATR Multiplier", type=input.float, step=0.1, defval=3.0) changeATR= input(title="Change ATR Calculation Method ?", type=input.bool, defval=true) atr2 = sma(tr, Periods) atr= changeATR ? atr(Periods) : atr2 up=src-(Multiplier*atr) up1 = nz(up[1],up) up := close[1] > up1 ? max(up,up1) : up dn=src+(Multiplier*atr) dn1 = nz(dn[1], dn) dn := close[1] < dn1 ? min(dn, dn1) : dn trend = 1 trend := nz(trend[1], trend) trend := trend == -1 and close > dn1 ? 1 : trend == 1 and close < up1 ? -1 : trend buySignal = trend == 1 and trend[1] == -1 sellSignal = trend == -1 and trend[1] == 1`

// strategy
`strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when=buySignal) strategy.exit("Long Stop Loss", "Long", stop=strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - stopLossPct/100), when=(time(squareOffTime) and sellSignal) or (time(squareOffTime) and not sellSignal)) strategy.exit("Long Take Profit", "Long", profit=strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + takeProfitPct/100), when=(time(squareOffTime) and sellSignal) or (time(squareOffTime) and not sellSignal))`

`plot(trend, title="Supertrend", style=plot.style_circles)`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `time()` function receives a resolution (timeframe). If you want resolution to be 15 minutes, you should use:

```
squareOffTime = input("15", title="Square Off Time")
```

not:

```
squareOffTime = input("15:00:00", title="Square Off Time")
```